# How can i scroll up down in android studio using ctrl + mouse

Tags: android-studio

How can i scroll up down in android studio using ctrl + mouse

for example there is a shortcut `ctrl + up arrow` to scroll up and `ctrl + down arrow` to scroll down but how can i scroll down - up using keyboard+ mouse ..

for example i need something like following

```
ctrl + move mouse to up => scroll up

ctrl + move mouse to down => scroll down
```

is there away to do it